# unix script calculate a list of slash 16 subnets

Tags: linux, bash, list, shell, ip

can you please help with a linux bash script to get/calculate  a list of subnets of /16 in one line, example: if you need all /16 subnets of 84.0.0.0/8, the result must be in text file like this:

```
84.0.0.0/16 84.1.0.0/16 84.2.0.0/16 ... 84.255.0.0/16
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Care to show what you've done so far so we can actually help you make it work?

Comment: `code`#!/bin/sh
for i in `seq 255`; do echo -n "84.$i.0.0/16 "; done; echo`code`
did so far this, but need to get all subnets in each file (/16) like for 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.254 for /16 subnets :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to wait for the result:

```
nmap -sn ipaddress/16 | grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

Scan the subnet silently and then grep for 1-3 digits . (3 times) plus 1 to 3 digits.